# android webRTC voice call

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, peerjs

I want to develop a voice call app for android. As the native android webRTC project is not maintained and lacks good documentation, I ended up using the peerjs library with webView. And it's working. But the problem is that webView doesn't provide any function to change the audio output stream. Audio is always played on the loudspeaker. I want it to be played on the earpiece. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself

```
//call only after the playback starts
fun setupAudio() {
        val am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
        //am.stopBluetoothSco()
        am.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
    }
```

Comment: great that you have found solution for this. can you please help me with how to stream music in this peerjs ? any advice for me?